# Users Register but Active table does not update with Jabberd2 on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xmpp

Users are able to register on my jabberd2 server, but they are unable to connect to add contacts and send messages.  It looks like to me that the active table is not updating when users register but I could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing my sm.log I found that I misconfiguration the database settings in */etc/jabberd2/sm.xml*

It was pebkac as I miss typed the password.